# jQuery Mobile sprites not displaying when css included as a local resource in a UIWebView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, uiwebview, jquery-mobile, sprite

On the iPhone I'm using a UIWebView to display some content that is stored on the device so my content can be viewed on the device when there is no internet connection.  I'm using the jQuery and mobile stuff in an attempt to create web apps and mobile apps that use one code base.

When I include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
```

everything works fine, the sprites that make up the back button, home icon etc. all work fine.  When I include the above as a local resource such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
```

The sprites do not display, I just get a dark circle where the sprite should appear.  All the other attributes defined in the css work fine, just not the sprites.  If I misname the local resource, everything is messed up, so I know the css as a local resource is being included, but it is being handled differently as a local resource vs a remote resource.  It even works if I hit the local dev box running apache... so it must have something to do with how the web server is serving the page vs. including it as a file......

I played around with loading the same page twice with separate UIWebViews in an attempt to see if there is some timing issue... since a local resource would load much quicker than a remote resource.  The second instance of the UIWebView loaded it correctly.  Is there a $.mobile command I can call to refresh the page, or for the library to do it's magic?

any ideas?

thanks for any help

Comment: even for local resources you should give direct paths

Comment: I didn't see iPhone listed in your dev profile, so I'll mention something you may not be aware of.  Resource files in an app bundle are located in the root directory for that app.  The second stylesheet inclusion example is the most direct URL you can give for a file on the device that I know of.

Answer (score 5):

Question was answered in the jQuery forum.  Funny, the answer was related to my comments above, and I still didn't think to look at the image files!  palm2forehead

> had to go in the jquery mobile css file and remove the references to the "images" directory.  IOS doesn't handle directories like normal systems so once I did that all was ok.

Comment: Had this same problem and dumping everything in the same directory fixed it. It's kind of a drag not being able to have a css directory though.

Answer (score 1):

It did not solve my issue chaning the path.
I had to look up in the mobile.css, i found that the icon were first set with an image, an then moved with classes, i had to set the the full background property on the classes that moved the background image.

Like so:

```
.ui-icon-plus {
background:#9c9c9c url(icons-18-white.png) no-repeat 0 50%; }
```

Old way were:

```
.ui-icon-plus {
background-position:-0 50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything (js,css) to www folder along with index.html file, and include file like this `<script src="jquery-mobile-min.js">``, it has solved my problem.